# Why are certain variables turning up nil?

Tags: json, swift, decoding

I'm trying to decode this json but certain variables are nil. Most of these seem to be okay it's just a few that are not working properly. I don't have much experience with swift so I'm kind of at a loss of what  to try next.

mycode:

```cs
struct Attr : Decodable {
        let page: String?
        let perpage: String?
        let totalpages: String?
        let total: String?
    }
    struct Images : Decodable {
        let text: String?
        let size: String?
    }
    struct Artist : Decodable {
        let name: String?
        let mbid: String?
        let url: String?
    }
    struct Streamable : Decodable {
        let text: String?
        let fulltrack: String?
    }
    struct Track : Decodable {
        let name: String?
        let duration: String?
        let playcount: String?
        let listeners: String?
        let mbid: String?
        let url: String?
        let streamable: Streamable?
        let artist: Artist?
        let images: [Images]?
    }
    struct Tracks : Decodable {
        let track:[Track]?
    }
    struct Container : Decodable {
        let tracks: Tracks?
        let attr: Attr?
    }
```

json:

```
{
  "tracks": {
    "track": [
      {
        "name": "bad guy",
        "duration": "0",
        "playcount": "870682",
        "listeners": "125811",
        "mbid": "",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Billie+Eilish/_/bad+guy",
        "streamable": {
          "#text": "0",
          "fulltrack": "0"
        },
        "artist": {
          "name": "Billie Eilish",
          "mbid": "",
          "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Billie+Eilish"
        },
        "image": [
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/88d7c302d28832b53bc9592ccb55306b.png",
            "size": "small"
          },
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/88d7c302d28832b53bc9592ccb55306b.png",
            "size": "medium"
          },
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/88d7c302d28832b53bc9592ccb55306b.png",
            "size": "large"
          },
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/88d7c302d28832b53bc9592ccb55306b.png",
            "size": "extralarge"
          }
        ]
      },
       ...
```

images should contain an array of Images instead of nil, the majority of the other variables seem to be okay though

Comment: Because the key is “#text”, not “text” in the image record. You can use CodingKey to map the property. Also I would suggest not using optional everywhere, set it only for properties where the json item actually can be null / missing

Comment: Also image in singular

Answer (score 0):

Add CodingKey enum to map fields with # in the name

```
struct Images : Decodable {
    let text: String?
    let size: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text = "#text"
        case size
    }
}

struct Streamable : Decodable {
    let text: String?
    let fulltrack: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text = "#text"
        case fulltrack
    }
}
```

You also have an error in your `Track`struct, change `images` to `image` (or use CodingKey mapping there to). For more on decoding json see [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Answer (score 0):

This is because when dealing with decodable the keys used in your serialized data format have to match the property names; In your case, the `Image` type contains `text` and `size` properties but the json contains `#text` and `size` (`text` =/= `#text`); That's also applicable for the type name `Images` not `image`.

However, [citing from Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types):

> If the keys used in your serialized data format don't match the
>   property names from your data type, provide alternative keys by
>   specifying String as the raw-value type for the `CodingKeys`
>   enumeration.

Add `CodingKeys` as:

```
struct Images : Decodable {
    let text: String?
    let size: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case text = "#text"
        case size
    }
}
```

---

*Tip:* it is useful to use `try/catch` when facing an error while decoding your data:

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Images.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

At this point it would print the error which might helpful to understand the issue most of the time.